# Method with int and int[] parameters

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method with two parameters but they are different types (int , int[]). The problem is in the caller, Eclipse will not compile because it says both of the parameters need to be integer types. The caller looks like this:

```
boolean uniqueTorF = isUnique(count, userArray[i]);
```

The method is this:

```
public static boolean isUnique(int oneCount, int[] multiCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < multiCount.length; i++) {
        if (oneCount == multiCount[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is my entire code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] userArray;
    userArray = new int[5];
    int validCount = 0, i = 0, uniqueSoFar = 0;

    System.out.println("Please print out 5 numbers between 50 and 100. ");
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (validCount < 5) {
        int count = entry.nextInt();

        boolean validTorF = isValid(count);
        boolean uniqueTorF = isUnique(count, userArray[i]);

        if (validTorF == true) {

            userArray[i] = count;
            validCount++;
            i++;

            if (uniqueTorF == true){
                uniqueSoFar++;
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid number.");
        }



    }
}

public static boolean isValid(int validParameter) {
    if (validParameter > 50 && validParameter < 100) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;

    }
}

public static boolean isUnique(int oneCount, int[] multiCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < multiCount.length; i++) {
        if (oneCount == multiCount[i]) {
            return false;

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know what type `userArray` is, but you are likely not passing the correct types to `isUnique()`.  `isUnque()` expects an `int` as its first parameter, and an `int` array (i.e. `int[]`) as its second parameter.

Comment: boolean uniqueTorF = isUnique(count, userArray[i]); 
what is the type of userArray?? is  it int[]

Comment: If you want an int array as the second parameter, why do you pass the element i from that array? Where does that i even come from? You have to pass userArray, not userArray[i]...

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the index `[i]`. `userArray[i]` is a single element of the array. `userArray` is the entire array.

```
boolean uniqueTorF = isUnique(count, userArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet it's saying the params ARE both integer types, not that they SHOULD BE.   You're passing `count` and `userArray[i]`, but you probably should be passing `count` and `userArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Defined method expects second argument as array whereas the caller is sending specific element. So send the entire array as argument

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is because you are passing the parameters wrongly...

When you do this:

```
boolean foo = isUnique(count, userArray[i]);
```

Then you are invoking the method with 2 int parameters,  but you need a int, int [] instead...

You are for sure looking for something more like this:

```
boolean foo = isUnique(count, userArray);
```